# App cannot be found by name, even week after published

Tags: google-play

I published my first app to play store, but it cannot be found by name ( HOP! ).
it can only be found if i search it by my name and then put the app's name (HOP! teemu ilomäki).

link - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.TeemuIlomaki.HOP

It has been a week now, and what i seen people say is that it takes only a couple hours to show up. The app is available in every country and every device. If you have answer please tell me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well, and it's complitely normal, because there are many apps on Google Play, so your app does not display even if you search for it, especially if there are many like that. It will display if you eventually get some downloads or promote it by paying, so that when searching that type of app it will be displayed before others who will have less downloads and rating than yours (or won't be promoted).

Hope this helped! :)

Comment: And do you know how the new and updated list works?

Comment: @TeemuIlomäki, All the apps have a "rank", that specifies where and after how many other apps they should be desplayed, also depending on the search the user did. There is not a specific number of downloads you need, the more you have, the higher it gets in the list of app that would come up in the same search. If there aren't many apps named like yours you might only need 2-3 downloads.